# WebXML parsing, Showing with Activity Indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

EveryBody
I have use one blog tutorial..
[See this link](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=493)

This works fine, I also us this xml's other tag and display.. But dont know where to set ActivityIndicator.. Is there any blog tutorial, please tell me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blog post about using activity indicators here:
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/use-activityindicator-in-iphone/

The most important pieces of code are:

```
[activityView startAnimating];
[activityView stopAnimating];

//To Test for a Conditional
[activityView isAnimating];
```

Comment: its very helpful about the only ActivityIndicator example, But i need as in XML parsing.. SO, you have any idea about this type of example please tell me.. Thanks..

Comment: There is an excellent tutorial that talks about picking the best parser for your project here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project and then goes into how to implement it here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml